# Gimp insists on changing Epson SC-P800 black to photo black on plain paper

Tags: gimp, epson

I'm trying to print an image on plain paper with an Epson SC-P800 printer using GIMP 2.10 on MacOS 10.14.6 (Mojave).  I can find no setting in the print or page-setup dialogs to set which black ink is used.  When I attempt to print the printer is prompting me to switch to Photo Black.

Has anyone made this work?

Comment: Why does it matter? If using black instead is really critical to your work have you considered exporting from Gimp and printing with a different application that provides better printer support? Does your image fit within the gamut that black produces?

Comment: Generally Gimp’s printing functionality provides convenience. Fine grained control is not always possible within it. Printing is very complex and Gimp development depends on volunteers. Epson could devote engineering time to making the Gimp experience flawless when using their printers. Epson doesn’t prioritize that.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use photo black ink for a photo? Photo black ink is optimized for printing photos on coated photo paper. Black pigment ink is optimized for printing text on plain uncoated paper. It's not for photos.

Comment: Michael C -  That's exactly the point. Photo Black is for coated photo paper.  I'm printing on plain paper.  I've told GIMP i'm printing on plain paper.  I've told the print dialog (which I'm guessing is Epson code) that I"m prining on plain paper.  But the printer insists on using photo black ink. ...and the only option is to cancel the print.

Comment: Maybe I'll try installing CUPS.  I used that once for a 15-foot long roll paper print on an Epson printer.  Other than that, Ben Rudgers seems to have the only solution.  Epson not only doesn't prioritize GIMP, they're awful at providing channels for user feedback.

Comment: I use Linux. CUPS is why I investigated the way GiMP prints (and Inkscape and Darktable). Eventually I bought Turboprint.But it’s for Linux.

Comment: If you’re printing a photo, photo black will be better on plain paper because true black is not a good representation of dark tones experienced by the human eye. One thing printing has taught me is that my intuition about color science is very poor relative to experts.

Comment: Ben, I agree that color science is far from intuitive!  Thank you for mentioning Turboprint!  Their website has a link to something called PrintFab for MacOS.  It looks promising if it's well integrated with Gimp.  It runs on Catalina so it is 64-bit code, and my P800 is on the supported printers list.. They have a 30-day free trial. I'll try it and report back here for the record.

Comment: @NetFool Even on plain paper pigment ink is not thin enough to to give decent gradations of grey lighter than absolute black. It's made to print fully black text with no gap between the droplets (leaving space between droplets is how one makes grey using black ink).

Comment: did you tried save the image into another format (like, png or pdf), then open and print it with some other software? The ink settings may disappear in the process.  ;)

Comment: @Michael C - The P800 uses the non-photo black ink when printing on Epson Matte papers.  It also has "Light Black" and "Light Light Black" inks. (It has 9 ink cartridges and is an 8-color printer with 2 modes one for glossy photo paper and the other for matte photo papers, watercolor paper and plain paper.)

Comment: @benrudgers - I installed the trial version of PrintFab for MacOS.  It looks like a wonderful print driver with lots of easy to understand controls.  There's a selector for ink type.  Sadly that button appears in the print dialog for every application I've tried EXCEPT GIMP.  GIMP even forces photo-black ink for images saved as a PDF and then printed in Apple's Preview.

Comment: I guess my only option is to file an issue with the development team and hope that the problem gets fixed in a future rev of GIMP.   I'll not sure where to do that, but I'll check GitHub and SourceForge to start.

Comment: You can always export and print with a different app. Or tell Gimp you’re using a different paper even though you are not.

Comment: @NetFool Light Black and Light Light Black are also dye based photo inks, not pigment inks.

Comment: @benrudgers - Which paper would you suggest?  Telling it I'm using plain paper certainly doesn't work.   I don't think StackExchange will let me post a screenshot, but here's what the print dialog looks like.   https://www.dropbox.com/s/nj58xf8u10jp5t5/Screen%20Shot%202020-12-01%20at%203.21.54%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: I thought your comment said it used black ink on photo matte paper.

Comment: @benrudgers. As the title of this thread says, it uses photo black on plain paper.  Also on matte paper, watercolor paper.   And if I was previously printing with non-photo black using a program that prints properly, when I try to print on plain paper with GIMP using the settings shown in the screenshot, it insists on changing to photo-black.  If export the file to a TIFF and try to print it with another program the print driver defaults to Photo Black and I have to change back manually for each print.

Comment: I’m glad you got it working.